# simplifying postgres queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

**Note: Asking to improve the working code.**

My `data` column is as follows

```
{
   "color":"red",
   "toy":{
      "id":27,
      "name":"Truck",
      "price":12,
      "available":true
   },
   "quantity":"12"
}
```

In the above data, I want to set `available` to **false** and `price` to **zero**.

To do this I Am using the below code.

```
UPDATE toys 
SET data=JSONB_SET(data, '{toy,available}','false') 
WHERE data->'toy'->>'id'='27';

UPDATE toys 
SET data=JSONB_SET(data, '{toy,price}','0') 
WHERE data->'toy'->>'id'='27';
```

My question is it possible to update both values in a single query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
UPDATE toys
SET data = jsonb_set(
              jsonb_set(data, '{toy,available}', 'false'),
              '{toy,price}',
              '0'
           )
WHERE data->'toy'->>'id'='27';
```